# External HD Damaged During File Transfer

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, data-recovery, hardware-failure

A friend was exporting a project from Final Cut Pro when his [external drive](http://reviews.costco.com/2070/11318289/western-digital-western-digital-500gb-my-passport-elite-hard-drive-reviews/reviews.htm) containing [this HD](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822136314) was disconnected and is no longer accessible.  He was using a mac and the drive is formatted for Extended Journaled.

I opened the plastic case, took out the drive and removed the SATA -> USB PCB to see if that had gone bad.  When used with another HD it worked perfectly. I also used a known working enclosure when testing just to be sure.

When the drive is plugged in, it makes a lower pitched buzz sound as if trying to start to spin up for about a second and then higher pitched buzz sound at then end.  The drive does that 5 times and then goes quiet.

I have tried connecting the drive to:

**iMac (OSX 10.7.5) via USB:** Saw (past tense), the volume was listed as 0kb with no partition, was not mountable.

Recognized a few times in Disk Utility but I'm not able to see it anymore.  When it was there I used the following software to no effect. *Disk Drill, Alsoft Diskwarrior, Stellar Phoenix Data Recovery, Wondershare Data Recovery.*

**Custom Rig (Win 7 Ultimate 64 bit/Ubuntu 14.10) connected straight to the motherboard:** Nothing

**Dell Latitude 3540 Laptop (Win 7 64bit) via USB:** Nothing

**Dell Vostro (Win 7 64bit & Ubuntu 14.10) via USB:** Win 7 Yes, Ubuntu nothing

It is seen in Devices and Printers as an External HDD and I can usually eject the drive properly from here.  In the Properties/hardware section it shows WD Disk drives at the bottom.  There is a mark for troubleshooting next to the icon but it comes up with No Problems Detected.  All drivers are up to date as far as windows is concerned.

Seen in Disk Manager as Not initialized, 0kb.  When I try to re-initialize the disk using MBR partition style I get the error *'Virtual Disk Manager: Incorrect Function'*

Seen in Diskpart/list disk as 0kb.  I selected the disk and was told that I successfully cleaned it once but then the disk disappeared from the list.

Used *Find and Mount* and saw it listed as WD with 0kb, scan returns nothing.

Used *testdisk* and saw nothing.

Used Western *DIgital Data LifeGuard Diagnostics*, the drive is seen and bad sectors are found, but when I try to repair them I get *'DLGDIAG for WIndows: Unable to repair bad sectors'*

I have spent days trying to get this to work and in the process I'm afraid I might be destroying the drive even further.  I was unable to see it most of yesterday on any computer.  I came across a post about using ddrescue in Linux to copy the drive contents over completely errors and all, but I can't even see the drive in Linux.

The only other thing I can think to do is to it up see if the head is stuck on the platter or there is some other physical problem.

Comment: Sounds like the drive is dead.  The sound it's making isn't good

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I'm looking for something slightly more specific then 'death' as a diagnosis. Anything I can do to at least figure out what has gone wrong, regardless of whether or not I can get the data back in the end would be nice.

Comment: Given the multiple things tried, resurrection isn't going to happen. Short of changing out the drive electronics (if possible with a like drive) which may have fried during the power interruption, it sounds like any further effort is a WOMBAT. Hence the terse answer by @Ramhound which is backed by years of experience. Reading the reviews on your Costco link is a really good indicator.

Comment: There isn't another answer other than death.  The drive failed mechanically outside of data recovery service which will place it in a clean room, remove the platters, and place them in an identical drive, you have no options.  The drive isn't even getting through it's self-tests if it's not spinning up...  Besides all your attempts likely killed any chance of data recovery